# Have any of the extensions of Frucht's theorem been put to good use in making other connections between group and graph theory?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

I am writing a survey paper on the topic of algebraic graph theory for my undergraduate graph theory course, and I am primarily concerned with the connections between group theory and graph theory, so one of the topics that I am covering is Frucht's theorem. As noted on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem) for Frucht's theorem, many extensions have been made to Frucht's theorem, strengthening the original theorem -- for example, that for every group $G$ there exists a cubic graph with $G$ as its automorphism group.

Certainly, this result is interesting in and of itself, but I was wondering if any research has been done to use this, or any of the other extensions of Frucht's theorem to further derive connections between graph theory and group theory.